# Do any openldap tools support the Authorization Identity Response Control?

Tags: fedora, ldap

I have a fedora 389 directory server and cannot use ldapwhoami because it is not supported.

However, 389-ds does support the following controls which are supposed to offer similar functionality:
2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.15
2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.16

Are there any openldap tools that support these controls and if so how do I use them?

I googled this, but couldn't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

No expert, but *very* unlikely. 389 server is descended from Netscape LDAP server, which was lightyears ahead of OpenLDAP. And AFAIU the gap hasn't closed significantly.

In any case, this is open source! Use Google, check the documentation. Who guarantees that I'm not lying through my teeth right now?